# Multi markers same location Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-maps-markers

How do I space out the markers that have the same coordinates ?

My code :

```
  function initialize() {

    var tasks = [
        [ 'title1', 44.833000, -0.567000, ],
        [ 'title2', 43.617000, 1.450000,],
        [ 'title3', 43.617000, 1.450000, ],
    ];

    var mapOptions = {zoom: 6, center: new google.maps.LatLng(46.8, 2),}

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {

      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(tasks[i][2], tasks[i][3]);

      var existingMarker = tasks[i];

      console.log(existingMarker)

      marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: latlng, title: tasks[i][1], map: map });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() { infowindow.setContent(tasks[i][0]); infowindow.open(map, marker);} })(marker, i));
    }

  }
```

How can I do ? (I removed some code for the example)